# Load multiple files by File-Type into ListView Control

Tags: vb.net, listview

How I can load files by File-Type?

I only wanna load **the video files(.ts)** from first the Loop and **(.srt) files** in the second Loop.

I tried, but I can't succeed in setting the Filter.

Here's the code by **jmcilhinney**

```
 Private Sub tbnAddFiles_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbnAddFiles.Click
    Dim vPaths As New List(Of String) 
    Dim vNames As New List(Of String)
    Dim sPaths As New List(Of String)
    Dim sNames As New List(Of String)

    Dim x As New OpenFileDialog
    x.Multiselect = True
    x.Filter = "TS and SRT File|*.ts;*.srt"
    x.RestoreDirectory = True

    If x.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

        'FOR VIDEO FILES (.ts)
        For Each f In x.FileNames
            vNames.Add(f)
            vPaths.Add(Path.GetFileName(f))
        Next

        'FOR SRT FILES (.srt)
        For Each f2 In x.FileNames
            sNames.Add(f2)
            sPaths.Add(Path.GetFileName(f2))
        Next

        AddToListView(vNames.ToArray, vPaths.ToArray, sNames.ToArray, sPaths.ToArray)

    End If
End Sub

Sub AddToListView(vNames As String(), sNames As String(), vPaths As String(), sPaths As String())
    LV.Items.Clear()

    Dim items As New List(Of ListViewItem)
    Dim upperBounds = {vNames.GetUpperBound(0), sNames.GetUpperBound(0), vPaths.GetUpperBound(0), sPaths.GetUpperBound(0)}

    For i = 0 To upperBounds.Min
        items.Add(New ListViewItem({vNames(i), sNames(i), vPaths(i), sPaths(i)}))
    Next

    LV.BeginUpdate()
    LV.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray())

    LV.EndUpdate()

End Sub
```

Comment: You should be creating your `OpenFileDialog` with a `Using` statement, so it will be automatically disposed at the end of the block. Also, use a better name than `x`. I tend to use abbreviations in such narrow scope but at least something meaningful. I tend to use the initials of the type, so `ofd` in this case.

Comment: Try this for Filter issue : `code` Using OFD As New OpenFileDialog
            With OFD
                .Filter = ("video files (*.st)|*.st|SRT files (*.srt)|*.srt")
                .Multiselect = True
                .RestoreDirectory = True
                If .ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                    'Your code here
                End If
            End With
        End Using `code`

Comment: Thank you jmc. 
Thank you for the suggestions. I'll do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the list using LINQ:

```vb
For Each f In x.FileNames.Where(Function(s) Path.GetExtension(s) = ".ts")
    vNames.Add(f)
    vPaths.Add(Path.GetFileName(f))
Next

'FOR SRT FILES (.srt)
For Each f In x.FileNames.Where(Function(s) Path.GetExtension(s) = ".srt")
    sNames.Add(f)
    sPaths.Add(Path.GetFileName(f))
Next
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for and also want to ask but I just forgot about LINQ.
I should learn about it. 
Thank you so much

Comment: Just last question.
How I can add array from first column?
I want to add text "Queued" for status display

Comment: I figured it out about the queued. I'll post the updated codes

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fixed and updated codes.
Big thanks to @jmcilhinney

```
 Private Sub btnAddFiles_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddFiles.Click
    Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        With ofd
            .Filter = ("video and srt files (*.ts;*.srt)|*.ts;*.srt")
            .Multiselect = True
            .RestoreDirectory = True
        End With

        If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim vPaths As New List(Of String)
            Dim sPaths As New List(Of String)
            Dim vNames As New List(Of String)
            Dim sNames As New List(Of String)
            Dim oNames As New List(Of String)

            txtinputFolder.Text = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName)

            For Each vid In ofd.FileNames.Where(Function(s) Path.GetExtension(s) = ".ts")
                vNames.Add(vid) 'input paths
                vPaths.Add(Path.GetFileName(vid)) 'intput filenames
                oNames.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(vid) & ".mkv") 'output file name
            Next

            For Each srt In ofd.FileNames.Where(Function(s) Path.GetExtension(s) = ".srt")
                sNames.Add(srt) 'input paths
                sPaths.Add(Path.GetFileName(srt)) 'input filenames
            Next

            AddToListView(vPaths.ToArray, sPaths.ToArray, oNames.ToArray, vNames.ToArray, sNames.ToArray)
        End If
    End Using
End Sub

Sub AddToListView(vPaths As String(), sPaths As String(), vNames As String(), sNames As String(), oNames As String())
    LV.Items.Clear()

    Dim items As New List(Of ListViewItem)
    Dim upperBounds = {vPaths.GetUpperBound(0), sPaths.GetUpperBound(0), vNames.GetUpperBound(0), sNames.GetUpperBound(0), oNames.GetUpperBound(0)}

    For i = 0 To upperBounds.Min
        items.Add(New ListViewItem({"Queued", vPaths(i), sPaths(i), vNames(i), sNames(i), oNames(i)}))
    Next

    LV.BeginUpdate()
    LV.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray())
    LV.EndUpdate()
    updateParameter()
End Sub
```